# How binary search tree is created?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose i am having an array say

```
1 5 4 6 8 9 10 22 17 7 9 3
```

I want to create a binary search tree from this array. I need algorithm to understand that.

I have read rest other things related to BST like `inorder traversal` `preorder` `postorder`, `tree walk`, `insertion deletion` etc

Book has not provided how to create BST. Need help here

Comment: Try the balancing binary tree, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree.

Comment: I think you are at the beginning of learning trees, don't care about balanced for now.

Comment: @GökhanÇoban: right. Just started learning trees. Some things in the book are not clear. So posting here

Comment: I would go in this order. 1. Binary tree (unbalanced) 2. AVL tree 3. Red Black tree 4.Splay tree

Answer (score 1):

if you do not care about the tree being balanced it is simple:

1. put the first element of the tree as the head.
2. iterate over the array. if an element is bigger than the node take a left(repeat the step for the left child) otherwise take a right(repeat the step for the right child).
3. if the left/right child is a null insert your new value there.

guaranteed to produce a binary search tree - just not a balanced one.

Comment: thanx for the answer but how to have balanced tree?

Comment: look here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree - wiki link complete with pseudo code. Good luck

Comment: But suppose first element is `1` then it will not create any tree

Comment: yes it will.. 1 is root, than 5 becomes its right child, than 4 becomes 5`s left child etc.

Comment: The link that you provided is for Red black trees. Can you provide me a link where it will show to create balanced binary trees, how to select root node

Comment: a red-black  tree is one implementation of a balancing binary tree. Yo can select any node as the root node, the time complexity remains O(n logn). I suggest you read the article and try to implement according to the pseudo code. Then you will truly understand the mechanics of this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should choose a root node for your BST. Once you have chosen a root node, it is already easy to construct a BST taking into consideration the fact that: **left children are less than the parent node and all right children are greater than the parent node.**

```
private Node root;

public void insert(int val) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(val);
    } else {
        insertHelper(root, val);
    }
}

private void insertHelper(Node node, int val) {
    if (val < node.val) {
        if (node.left == null) {
            node.left = new Node(val);
        } else {
            insertHelper(node.left, val);
        }
    } else if (node.val < val) {
        if (node.right == null) {
            node.right = new Node(val);
        } else {
            insertHelper(node.right, val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to select root node.

Comment: It depends on you. You can choose whatever root node you want depending on the circumstance. Of course, the tree's structure depends on the root node you chose.

Answer (score 0):

If the given array is sorted, you can do the following:

1. Take the middle element of the array and make it the root of the tree
2. Take the left sub-array and make it the left sub-tree of the root recursively
3. Take the right sub-array and make it the right sub-tree of the root recursively

Otherwise you can always sort the array before applying the procedure

```
struct node* construct(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if(start>end)
       return;
    else if (start==end)
    {
    /*assuming we have a function newNode(int) which creates a new BST Node*/
        node* Node = newNode(arr[start]);
        return Node;
    }
    int mid  = (start+end)/2;
    node* root = newNode(arr[mid]);
    root->left = construct(arr,start,mid-1);
    root->right = construct(arr,mid+1,end);
    return root;
}
```