# Binary Search Trees / Picking a Root

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm not quite sure how to pick a root for a binary search tree (I'm wanting to do without any code):

5, 9, 2, 1, 4, 8 ,3, 7, 6

How do I pick a root?

The steps are confusing me for this algorithm.

Comment: When you say "this algorithm", is there a specific algorithm that you have in mind? (I ask because there is *not* a single well-known way to pick a root.)

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an empty BST (binary search tree), then iterate the list and insert each item.

You don't need to pick a root, just build the tree. But maybe you want balanced the tree, you can insert as first element the middle value of the list, but the right answer is to use a balanced binary search tree (AVL tree).

Answer (score 1):

Median number will be a better choice, because you want to have less depth. 
Here is one example, the root is find the median the next one is also find the median

```
                 5 
          3             8
    2         4       7    9
 1                  6
```

5 is get by (1+9)/2.  3 get from ceiling(1+4)/2 (you can also choose the floor of the median as the role of choosing median root)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pick a root?

In whichever way you want to. Any number of your data can be the root.

---

You would like to choose the median though, in this case, 5. With that choice, your tree should get as balanced as it gets, four nodes on the left of 5 and four nodes in the right subtree of 5.

Notice that *any* element could be the rood (even a random choice, or the first number in your example).

---

> Um, then why should I worried finding the median and not always picking the first number (easiest choice)?

Because you want your Binary Search Tree (BST) to be as **balanced** as possible.

If you pick the min or the max number as a root, then your tree will reach its maximum depth (worst case scenario), and will emulate a single linked list, which will result in a worst case scenario for the search algorithm as well. However, as Michel stated, picking the minimum or maximum item for the root won't necessarily lead to a degenerate tree. For example, if you picked the minimum item for the root and but the right branch that contains the rest of the items is balanced, then the tree's height is only one level more than optimum. You only get a degenerate tree if you choose the nodes in ascending or descending order.

Keep in mind that in a BST, this rule must be respected:

*Left children are less than the parent node and
all right children are greater than the parent node.*

---

For more, read [How binary search tree is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966081/how-binary-search-tree-is-created)?

Comment: Picking the minimum or maximum item for the root won't necessarily lead to a degenerate tree. For example, if you picked the minimum item for the root and but the right branch that contains the rest of the items is balanced, then the tree's height is only one level more than optimum. You only get a degenerate tree if you choose the nodes in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Great @JimMischel, I agree, hope you like my answer more now!

Answer (score 0):

BST with the same values can have many forms. For example, a tree containing 1,2 can be:

```
1  <- root
 \
  2  <-- right son
```

or

```
    2  <- root
   /
  1  <-- left son
```

So you can have a tree where 1 is the root and it goes 1->2->3... and no left sons. You can have 5 as the root with 4 and 6 as left and right sons respectively, and you can have many other trees with the same values, but different ordering (and maybe different roots)